# Как лучше передавать конфиг по "цепочке обязанностей"

Tags: php, ооп

```
    new PaymentOf(
        new ConcreatePaymentSystem(
            new CardForm(
                $_POST
            )
        )
    );
```

Сейчас пишу небольшую библиотеку, для подключения платежных систем (на продакшене себя хорошо зарекомендовала). Но вот вопрос. в PaymentOf нужно передать конфиг бд для записи значений.
в  ConcreatePaymentSystem нужно передать конфиг для авторизации сайта на стороне платежной системы (так называемые секретный и публичный ключи). 
Как это сделать элегантно и хорошо.
Вот пример конфига который организовал

```
    $config = new Config(
    [
        'secret' => [
            'secret_key' => '',
            'auth_key' => '',
        ],
        'db' => [
            'db_host' => '', //with db
            'db_name' => '', //with db
            'username' => '', //with db
            'password' => '', //with db
            'db_type' => 'mysql' //with db
        ],
        'urls'=>[
            'callback_url'=>'',//default
            'after_payment_url'=>'', //default
            'fail_url'=>'', //default
            'success_url'=>'', //default
        ]
    ]
);
```

Также преследую цель простоты, удобности и расширяемости. Также мне бы хотелось сделать так чтобы и новичек разобрался как с этим работать.
заранее благодарю за ответы.

Comment: суть вопроса не ясна

Comment: можно организовать пространство имён namespace и внутри него объявить переменную $config глобально как вариант